# Finding Image EigenVector and Eigenvalue

Tags: matlab, feature-detection, matlab-guide

I am new to the concept of feature detection. I calculated eigenvectors and eigenvlues of a matrix simply by using `lambda=eig(Matrix)`. I want to know how to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors of gray scale image. Thank You.

Comment: You do it the same. `Matrix` will be just a matrix containg gray-scale level values.

Comment: No.. In 'MATRIX' i just give random values.

Comment: Eigenvectors and and eigenvalues are defined with respect to operators. While an image is stored as a 2-dimensional array, just like a matrix representing an operator (in some basis), it doesn't make sense to talk about it having eigenvalues and eigenvectors. What are you trying to do? Perhaps compress a image?

Comment: No..actually i want to detect corner points of an image.. by applying threshold to ..if the (-)lambda value is less than then threshold i applied to it.. it show me the corner.

Comment: i have done it through by giving random number in matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eig function accepts a square matrix of type double or single as input. First convert the image from grayscale (uint8 or uint16) to double, and then make it square. See the following code example:

%Read in some grayscale image:

```
    Matrix = imread('lena_gray.jpg');
```

%Convert image to double precision to use eig function:

```
    imtype = class(Matrix);
    Matrix = double(Matrix);
```

%Find a square matrix that fits image for eig operation:

```
    sz = size(Matrix);
    m = max(sz);
    mx = zeros(m, m);
    mx(1:sz(1),1:sz(2)) = Matrix;
```

%Find eigenvectors and eigenvalues:

```
    [V, D] = eig(mx);
```

%check that the matrix generates A using matrix factorization and convert back to original 
image:

```
    eval(['A = ',imtype,'(abs(V*D*V^(-1)));']);
    figure
    imshow(A)
```

Comment: Its output is the same gray pictures without any change

Comment: The columns of V are the eigenvectors of A, and D is a diagonal matrix with corresponding eigenvalues, where A*V = V*D or A = V*D*V^(-1).